# TODO list with vanilla Markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to write a TODO list in a **vanilla** Markdown file. I know that there is a solution with [GitHub flavored Markdown](https://github.blog/2014-04-28-task-lists-in-all-markdown-documents/):

```
- [ ] TODO#1
- [x] TODO#2, but this one is done !
```

But I want to have the same result with the preview feature in VSCode (it does not render at all - I am left with `[]` in the preview panel).

**Is there a way to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which markdown extension you are using. On my installation, it shows correctly with *markdown all in one* extension. It renders it as long as you leave an empty space between brackets (that is `[ ]` instead of `[]`)

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't using `Markdown All in One`. Now it renders correctly. Thank you !